# How to change node value

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

```
    func createBall(){
        ballS = SKNode()
        let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")

        saw.zPosition = 2
        ballS.addChild(ball)
        self.addChild(ballS)
}
```

This creates a Ball node with z position 2. But while running the game, I want to create another ball that has a z position at 1. How can I do this, or do I have to make a whole new function that makes a ball node with z position 1?

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of subclassing SKSpriteNode?

Comment: What is `self` here?

Comment: I prefer not to make a subclass - and self is class GameScene - also I just decided to add an int inside the class, and added something like `if counter == 2{saw.zPosition = 1}else{saw.zPosition = 2}`

Answer (score 0):

If each `ball` sprite has to be a child of the `ballS` node, then you could do the following.

Define ballS as a property (i.e. after the `class` definition but before any functions)

```
let balls = SKNode()
```

in `didMove(to:)`, add the `ballS` Node:

```
addChild(ballS)
```

Create a `addBall` function: (don't call it `createBall` unless all it does create the ball)

```
func addBall(withZPosition zPos: Int) {
    let newBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")
    newBall.zPosition = zPos
    ballS.addChild(newBall)
    }
```

Then simply call `addBall(withZPosition:)` to create and add a new ball:

```
addBall(withZPosition: 2)
```

If you want more control over the ball that is created (e.g. you want to change some of it's properties before adding it to the scene), you can make a `createBall` function that creates a new ball and returns the new node:

```
func createBall(withZPosition zPos: Int) -> SKSpriteNode {
    let newBall = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")
    newBall.zPosition = zPos
    return newBall
    }
```

and use this as follows:

```
let newBall = createBall(withZPosition: 2)
newBall.size = CGSize(x: 50, y:50)
ballS,addchild(newBall)
```

Answer (score 0):

U can have a global variable so that whenever you want to change u set it and create the ball

so create a variable

```
var myZposition = 2
```

and create a ball at the start in didmove to view by calling createBall()

```
   func createBall(){
    ballS = SKNode()
    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")

    saw.zPosition = myZPosition
    ballS.addChild(ball)
    self.addChild(ballS)
 }
```

then after these if you want to change the zPosition just set it at the end of didmove to view

```
myZposition = 1
```

Then whenever u create balls from here your zPosition would be 1. This would be an easy setup if you have lots of balls and implement a change in zPosition for reaching a specific area of the game
Hope this helped

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted you, but I don't have enough reputation for it to show. Sorry!

Comment: It's ok, glad to have helped.

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest to use an argument, like:

```
func createBall(z: Int) {
    ballS = SKNode()
    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")

    saw.zPosition = z
    ballS.addChild(ball)
    self.addChild(ballS)
```

}

And use it as:

```
createBall(z: 2)
```

Comment: Not sure why I was downvoted, any feedback is welcome.

Comment: I upvoted you, but it won't show because I have low reputation. Thanks!